# ListFragment getListView is null

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-listfragment

I am making a list that will be placed under another view.
Based on the other article, i should contain the other view in the header of the listview.
I am using ListFragment and will be attached to several activity. So I am creating a method to set the header of the ListFragment.

The problem is the getListView() method is returning null, although I call the addHeader after the list is shown.

Why is the the getListView() is always null?

Here is my code:

```
public class NewsListFragment extends ListFragment {

private final int topNewsCount = 5;

private DBNewsDataSource dataSource;
private Activity myActivity;
private Context myContext;
private boolean isHome;

@Override
  public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    isHome = true;
    myActivity = getActivity();

    Bundle extras = myActivity.getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        isHome = extras.getBoolean("isHome");
    }

    dataSource = new DBNewsDataSource(getActivity());
    dataSource.open();

    List<DBNews> news = dataSource.getAllNews();
    List<String> titleList = new ArrayList<String>();
    dataSource.close();

    for(int i = 0; i< (isHome?topNewsCount:news.size()); i++)
    {
        titleList.add(news.get(i).getTitle());
    }

    NewsListArrayAdapter adapter = new NewsListArrayAdapter(getActivity(),news,titleList,isHome);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

  }

  @Override
  public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // Do something with the data

  }

  public void addHeader(View v)
  {
      ListView lv = getListView();
      lv.addHeaderView(v);
  }
```

Here is the activity that call the Fragment

```
public class HomeActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.template_activity_home);
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    NewsListFragment frgNews = new NewsListFragment();
    MainSlideShowFragment frgSS = new MainSlideShowFragment();
            View vw = frgSS.getView();
    frgNews.addHeader(vw);
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.layout_news_list , (Fragment) frgNews);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

    //frgNews.addHeader(vw);
}
```

Comment: I can not see where do you call addHeader.

Comment: i call it on  the activity which i want to include the news list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override onCreate view and let it returns a View wich contains a ListView with id `android:id="@android:id/list"`

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cart_list,
            null);
    return view;
}
```

Comment: should i create a new layout xml or just adding a listview inside the layout in the template_activity_home?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a fragment but haven't called

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     // Inflate the layout for this fragment
     return inflater.inflate(R.layout.example_fragment, container, false);
     }
```

This is where the layout will be inflated. Hence it is null as it is not yet inflated.

Comment: what is R.layout.example_fragment? is that the layout which is used by the activity?

Comment: It is the layout used for your fragment. Replace that with a reference to your fragment's layout.